# PlayFramework. JSONP view. How?

Tags: java, playframework, jsonp

I need that controller return JSONP response.

Something like this:

```
jsonp123({"name" : "Remy", "id" : "10", "blog" : "http://site.com"});
```

I know, that PlayFramework can send response as html Template, JSON, XML... but how send JSONP response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at how it's done for JSON (`renderJSON()` throws a [`RenderJson`](https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/src/play/mvc/results/RenderJson.java) object) and implement JSONP response in a similar way. The only difference is that you need to surround Gson output with a function call and that content type should be `text/javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header type to "text/javascript"  and then call renderText.  (The render methods only set the mime type if you don't.)